# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: GIT_PASSWORD for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have checked all the topics on the same mistake, tried everything, and yet I was unable to find anything to help me solving my issue.

my code builds a docker container, starts a flask application and run a python script, run tests and then should merge Master. The code is the following :

```
pipeline {
agent any

stages {



   stage('Master merging'){
      
      steps{
         script{
         passwordVariable = 'password'
         usernameVariable = 'unsername'
            // Variables for input
         if(env.BRANCH_NAME == 'features'||env.BRANCH_NAME == 'main'){
         sh 'git checkout origin/features'
         sh 'git pull'
         sh 'git remote update'
         sh 'git fetch'
         sh 'git checkout origin/main'
         sh 'git merge origin/features'
         withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId : 'GitHub', passwordVariable:'GIT_PASSWORD', usernameVariable:'GIT_USERNAME')]){
            sh "git push http://${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}@github.com/Username/Repo.git"
         }
         }}
   }
   }

   }
}
```

when I arrive to stage('master merging'), I have the following mistake

```
Masking supported pattern matches of $GIT_PASSWORD
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (container shutdown)
Stage "container shutdown" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: GIT_PASSWORD for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer :)

Prerequisites : create a credential on Manage jenkins -> Manage credentials -> jenkins -> Global credentials (unrestricted) -> username with password. Inquire github username as username and [Personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) as password. ID is up to you.

Code :

```
stage('Master merging'){
      
      steps{
         script{

            // Variables for input
         if(env.BRANCH_NAME == 'features'||env.BRANCH_NAME == 'main'){
         sh 'git checkout features'
         sh 'git pull'
         sh 'git remote update'
         sh 'git fetch'
         sh 'git checkout origin/main'
         sh 'git merge features'
         sh "git config user.email \"GITHUB EMAIL\""
         sh "git config user.name \"GITHUB USERNAME\""
withCredentials([gitUsernamePassword(credentialsId:'ID you inquired in credentials')]) {

sh 'git push https://github.com/Username/Repo.git'

               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```